# Nginx Clojure Startup issue on windows

Tags: nginx, clojure, path, jvm

Nginx Configuration for jvm path and classpath :

> jvm_path ..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll;
>   jvm_classpath "..\lib\*";

This works fine and nginx gets started in Windows server 2012 operating system. But getting error

```
"jvm may be mad for wrong options! See hs_err_pid****.log for detail!" 
 on Windows 10.
```

Setting jvm_path to auto works in Windows 10. But my requirement is to specify path relative to auto-config with all operating systems. Kindly suggest a solution if anyone has faced similar issue.

Comment: Can you post a `.conf` file? My guess is that it is a path issue. May need to escape backslashes or change to forward slashes which would make it a bit more portable...